# Translate child of div, when div itself is translated

Tags: html, css

I have an html element

```
<div class="mycluster" style="margin-left: -22px; margin-top: -22px; width: 44px; height: 44px; transform: translate3d(383px, 217px, 0px); z-index: 217;">
  35
</div>
```

that's being generated by a javascript library I'm using. With styles, its basically a blue marker on a map with text displaying "35" on top. The problem I have is that the "35" is too high in the marker, so I need to translate it down using `translateY()`, but that's being overwritten by the div's `translate3d()`.

I tried using

```
.mycluster:first-child {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
```

and

```
div.mycluster > div:first-child {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
```

but neither worked. I can't change how the element is initially rendered.

**Edit**
Here's an image, I want to vertically center the numbers in the markers.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the *positioning*:

```css
.mycluster {
  background: blue;
}

.mycluster > span {
  position: relative; /* positioned relative to its normal position */
  top: 100px; /* moved down by 100px */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycluster" style="margin-left: -22px; margin-top: -22px; width: 44px; height: 44px; transform: translate3d(383px, 217px, 0px); z-index: 217;">
  <span>35</span>
</div>
```